# Can I conclude that a computer that won't turn on until waiting has a bad power supply?

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting

First I started receiving blue screens, then the Pc would just restart, and finally it would shutoff even when booted from a usb. Finally one time it wouldn't turn on until I waited for about a minute. That wait is a definite sign that it's the power supply or could it still be the mobo?

Comment: Look, it really could be either. There's no telling until you find some hard evidence as a motherboard problem can have the same symptoms.

Comment: ah I was afraid of that. All shops are closed for 2 weeks and I don't have a spare to try.

Comment: Check the motherboard for Bulging-Leaking capacitors, if you find any its time for a new mobo or PC.

Comment: Both are 2-3 months old, so I figured I put too much on a 500w psu, but the "how much power" site said I need 470watts when I put in all my components and models and the measured wattage at the outlet was only 150

Comment: @user5389726598465 Maybe test with some devices removed.